# Python Pandas, translating start-end events into single consolidated Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to optimise the translation and consolidation of event data into a single dataframe. I first create an empty dataframe with a unique list of column keys (C) to reflect the individual units and set all values to zero.

The list of lists, `output_summary` takes the following form (2000+rows, ~300 unique units, but some repeated):

```
# unit,start_date,end_date,value

[['X1','01/01/2015','01/01/2016',100],
['X2','03/05/2015','06/07/2015',200],
['X1','01/08/2015','25/09/2015',50],
...,
['X300','06/06/2015','05/07/2016',150]]
```

The code below loops through each event in `output_summary`, creates a separate time series and adds it to `empty_df` using the same datetime index. The problem is that the addition of two dataframes is time intensive. Are there any speedier solutions?

```
start_date = date(2012,1,1)
end_date = date(2018,1,1)
dr = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.datetools.day)
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(index = dr, columns=C)
empty_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

for row in output_summary:
    dr = pd.date_range(datetime.strptime(row[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date(), datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date(), freq=pd.datetools.day)
    dr=pd.TimeSeries(row[3], index=dr)
    df= pd.DataFrame(data=dr)
    df.columns=[row[0]]
    empty_df=empty_df.add(df, fill_value=0,axis=0)
```

Comment: `for row in output_summary` would make `row` iterate through the column names of `output_summary`. Did you mean `for idx, row in output_summary.iterrows()` instead?

Comment: output_summary is a list of lists, the headers above are for reference only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slight alteration of your code which speeds it up significantly.  The
main idea is to delay working with the big `empty_df` for as long as possible.
Instead add small(er) Series together and store the result in a dict. Then build
the resulting DataFrame using the dict of Series and `reindex` to generate
`empty_df` only at the end.

Below, `orig` is the original code you've posted, and `alt` is an alternative
version. Here is a benchmark with an `output_summary` of 4 rows:

```
In [224]: %timeit orig(output_summary)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.8 ms per loop

In [225]: %timeit alt(output_summary)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop
```

Here is a benchmark with an `output_summary` of 2000 rows:

```
output_summary = output_summary*500
In [227]: %timeit orig(output_summary)
1 loops, best of 3: 9.21 s per loop

In [228]: %timeit alt(output_summary)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.07 s per loop
```

So for these cases, `alt` is faster than `orig` by a factor of 8-11.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT

output_summary = [['X1', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016', 100],
                  ['X2', '03/05/2015', '06/07/2015', 200],
                  ['X1', '01/08/2015', '25/09/2015', 50],
                  ['X300', '06/06/2015', '05/07/2016', 150]]

def alt(output_summary):
    data = {}
    for col, start_date, end_date, value in output_summary:
        dr = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
        series = pd.Series(value, index=dr)
        data[col] = data.setdefault(col, pd.Series()).add(series, fill_value=0)
    result = pd.DataFrame(data)

    start_date = DT.date(2012,1,1)
    end_date = DT.date(2018,1,1)
    dr = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
    result = result.reindex(dr)
    result = result.fillna(0)
    return result

def orig(output_summary):
    start_date = DT.date(2012,1,1)
    end_date = DT.date(2018,1,1)
    dr = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.datetools.day)
    C = sorted(set([row[0] for row in output_summary]))
    empty_df = pd.DataFrame(index = dr, columns=C)
    empty_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    for row in output_summary:
        dr = pd.date_range(
            pd.Timestamp(row[1]).date(),
            pd.Timestamp(row[2]).date(),
            freq=pd.datetools.day)
        dr = pd.TimeSeries(row[3], index=dr)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=dr)
        df.columns=[row[0]]
        empty_df = empty_df.add(df, fill_value=0, axis=0)
    return empty_df
```

---

Sanity check:

```
In [231]: df1 = orig(output_summary)

In [232]: df2 = alt(output_summary)

In [233]: df1.equals(df2)
Out[233]: True
```